# What is the difference between Date.now() and Date.now in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using `Date.now()` and `Date.now` in mongoose model.

I am a little bit confused about the difference between them. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Date.now` can be used in your Mongoose schema definition to set a default value for a field, whereas `Date.now()` is the JavaScript equivalent. For example, when setting a default value in your schema definition, you use `Date.now`. With this schema definition, Mongoose will populated `createdDate` with the current time.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//schema
var yourSchema= new Schema({
   text: {type: String},
   createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

However, when writing JavaScript code against your schema, you have to use `Date.now()`

```
yourSchema.pre('save', function doSomething(next){
   var something = this;
   something.createdAt(Date.now());
   next();
 });
```

Comment: But if I used Date.now() to my schema definition to set default value then what will happened? I mean can i use Date.now() to set default value??

Comment: `Date.now` is replaced by Mongoose with the current datetime when creating a new record, so it will change for every record. However, if you would use `Date.now()` your default value will be set to a fixed value (the creation time of your schema).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer #Jaco

Answer (score 43):

I know this is an old question, but the accepted answer doesn't explain the difference properly. It explains the difference in behaviour, but not how it actually works.

In your `mongoose` schema, your `default` can be either a value of the specified type or a function that returns a value of the specified type. `Date.now` is a built in Javascript function that returns the current unix timestamp as a number.

If you pass `Date.now` as the `default` in your `mongoose` schema, you are passing the function and `mongoose` will call that function every time a document needs a default value for that property. This results in the current time, **at the time of *document* creation**, being stored as the value for that property.

However, if you pass `Date.now()` instead, you are passing the value returned by `Date.now()` rather than the function. By doing this, your documents will get the current time, **at the time of *schema* creation**, as the default value for that property. This means that your documents will store the time of the latest deployment, which is probably not what you want.

If `Date.now` was a constant "replaced by Mongoose with the current datetime when creating a new record", as suggested by the accepted answer, then the following should logically work:

```
validUntil: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now + 3*60*60*1000 // 3 hours from now
}
```

But `Date.now` is not magically replaced by `mongoose`, it's a function and you can't add a number to a function. However, you can call a function inside your own function and add a number to the result, as demonstrated below:

```
validUntil: {
  type: Date,
  default: () => Date.now() + 3*60*60*1000 // 3 hours from now
}
```

As it wasn't clear from the accepted answer that `Date.now` is a function and not a `mongoose` constant, I wanted to clarify that. The difference between `Date.now()` and `Date.now` is that `Date.now()` calls the function and returns the result, while `Date.now` returns the function itself.

Comment: This answer provides the important clarification that the value provided to a mongoose schema `default` will be invoked if it is a function. With this knowledge you will now be able to understand more advanced use cases of the default schema option.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the detailed answer. Can you please clarify this a bit more "By doing this, your documents will get the current time, at the time of schema creation, as the default value for that property. This means that your documents will store the time of the latest deployment,"? What do we mean exactly by "at the time of schema creation" and "latest deployment"?