# Node js and mongoose schema date.now code not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created this schema for user registration:

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lname: String,
    fname: String,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    registrationDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    referedBy: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    referalEnd: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now() + 5*365*24*60*60*1000
    },
    userRefererId: {
        type: String,
        default: uniqid()
    }
});
```

As you can see, there is a `Date.now` function and `uniqid` function in the schema.

Those functions can be used approximately once every 5 minutes,
because if I create two users a few seconds apart, it generates the same uniqid and shows the same date.

[image: Image of my MongoDB collection]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this before, the schema is generated at deployment / start time and not regenerated on each new creation hence why the time is always the same. Its better to generate the date / time outside the `new Model().save()` call.

Answer (score 12):

Remove the () from `Date.now()` and just call `Date.now`.

Comment: checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136808/6908282) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lname: String,
    fname:String,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    registrationDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: function(){return Date.now()}
    },
    referedBy: {
        type:String,
        default: ''
    },
    referalEnd: {
        type: Date,
        default: function(){ return Date.now()  + 5*365*24*60*60*1000}
    },
    userRefererId: {
        type:String,
        default: uniqid()
    }
});
```

Comment: `default: function(){return Date.now()}` doesn't work either.