# show schedules based on today date mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to show schedules based on userid and display the dates which are only greater than and equal to today's date. Here is my code:

```
router.get('/schedule/viewschedule/:id',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {   
    const schedule = await Schedule.find({$and:[{userid:req.params.id},{enddate:{$gte:Date.now}}]}).sort({startdate: 1})
    return res.json(schedule)    
});
```

I am stuck at the enddate field and am not able to show schedules that is $gte. Where did I get it wrong?

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Date.now() instead of Date.now

Date.now is just the function, Date.now() will actually call the function and give you the value.
So when you use "$gte: Date.now" you're trying to compare the enddate to a function, which won't work.

Their difference is explained well by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136808/13058686