# There is no calibration between MongoDB UTC time and local time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

Data is stored and inquired through the `API` on the web page, and the `API` is using `MongoDB`.

The server space has been unified to `UTC` time so that the same results can be achieved in different time zones.

**`MongoDB` uses the `Mongoose schema` as follows**:

```
    const userSchema = new Schema({
     userId : {
      type : String
     },
     score : {
      type : Number
     },
     createdAt : {
      type : Date,
      default : Date.now
     }
    });
```

Because `Date.now` in the schema is in the `createdAt` field by default, it does not pass the Date value separately when querying the `create` or `update` of `mongoose`.

Considering the case where `offset` exists based on `UTC` time, the time is calculated using `moment.js` as follows:

```
    // -540 offset value for KST 9 hours faster than UTC
    const utc= moment.utc().add(offset, 'm').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
    
    let beginDate = new Date(utc);
    let endDate = null;
    let year = beginDate.getFullYear();
    let month = beginDate.getMonth();
    let date = beginDate.getDate();
    
    // To view the full duration of the day
    beginDate = new Date(new Date(year, month, date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    endDate = new Date(new Date(year, month, date).setHours(23, 59, 59, 59));
    
    // Find document
    const user = await userSchema.aggregate([
     {
      $unwind : 'lists'
     },
     {
      $match : {
       'lists.createdAt' : {
         $gte : beginDate,
         $lte : endDate
       }
      }
     },
     ...
    ]);
```

For example, if you make a query in `Korea`, the data inquiry may differ from the time after `midnight` and to `9 a.m.` the next day.

What is wrong with the above parallax correction logic? I don't exactly understand the current problem.

Comment: I have no clue about mongoose, but should it be rather `default : new Date()`?

Comment: I saw this article and decided to write `default: Date.now` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501273/what-is-the-difference-between-date-now-and-date-now-in-mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so difficult? Simply use

```
{
  $match : {
   'lists.createdAt' : {
     $gte : moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
     $ltr : moment().endOf('day').toDate()
   }
  }
 }
```

`moment().startOf('day').toDate()` returns the begin of current day in your local time zone. I live in Switzerland, thus it returns `ISODate("2023-01-17T23:00:00.000Z")`

But you can specify also a time zone, e.g.

```
moment.tz('Asia/Seoul').startOf('day').toDate();
ISODate("2023-01-17T15:00:00.000Z")
```

The problem is `moment.utc().add(...)` **really modifies** the time value. But that is not what you need to do, you like to change only the way how the time is **displayed** in your local time zone.

For comparison and calculations, the displayed value does not matter. All methods are done in UTC time only.

Comment: I think I'm complicating my thoughts too much.

Should I add() the offset value among the logic created above when mapping to the day of the week of a specific time zone after the inquiry, not just for a simple period of inquiry?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In general, **never** use `add()/subtract()` related to time zones. Use the built in functions [Converting to Zone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/), if you need to do conversion.

Comment: If you need to convert to various timezones, you should use `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` to get the time zone from the client and use it.