# Mongoose model saves default date as that of last time the server was started at

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, momentjs

I have this mongoose model

```
const reportUsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  texts: [
    {
      text: { type: String, default: "" },
      date_time: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
    },
  ],
});
```

I want this:

Whenever a new text is pushed in the `texts` field I want to insert the current datetime.

What I am getting (Problem):

I am getting the same date time when I restarted the server last time. For example if I have restarted the server 2 days ago I am getting the 2 days before date, which is wrong.

What I have tried:

1. Using moment.js: I have tried multiple combinations of moment.js too. Adding them here:

```
date_time: { type: Date, default: moment() }
```

And

```
date_time: { type: Date, default: moment().format() }
```

And

```
date_time: { type: Date, default: moment().utc(true) }
```

And

```
date_time: { type: Date, default: moment().utc(true).format() }
```

2. Using the built-in Date()

I am using it currently in the above code but none of above worked for me.

Note: The thing that worked is instead of depending upon this default value from the mongoose model, I have passed the current datetime value alongwith the text. And this is working well.

I could not understand the behavior. Help me understand where I was wrong.

Mongoose version: 5.10.7

**Edit**

I know `new schema` thing. I want to know what I am doing wrong that mongoose is behaving like this. I want to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The default: new Date() option in the schema means that the date_time field will have a default value of the current date and time when the document is created or when the field is not specified.

You can use the timestamps option:

```
let ItemSchema = new Schema({
  texts: [
    {
      text: { type: String, default: "" },
    },
  ],
},
{
  timestamps: true
});
```

You can also specify the timestamp fileds:

```
timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }
```

Comment: I know that I can do that. Thanks for it. But I want to know why it is behaving like that? Does the mongoose schema depends on the last restart of server? or something like that? I want to know this. Can you help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77451972/21972629) answer you need to update your schema to use `Date.now` instead of `new Date()` like this:

```js
const reportUsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  texts: [
    {
      text: { type: String, default: "" },
      date_time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, //< This change
    },
  ],
});
```

This is because when you use `default: new Date()` you are telling the schema to use a default date **at the time the schema was defined**, not the document. So if you deploy your app to a server and then start up your app the default value for that field in that schema will be the time your app started.

However, if you use `Date.now` then mongoose knows to set the default to use the datetime **at the time of document creation**.

In the mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) they do recommend this:  `updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },` in their kitchen sink example. They also list it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions) in their Default Functions example.

In summary, when you use `new Date()` you **called the function** so use the return value. If you use `Date.now` you **pass the function** (`Date.now()`) so call it at document creation time.

Comment: I know that I can do that. Thanks for it. But I want to know why it is behaving like that? Does the mongoose schema depends on the last restart of server? or something like that? I want to know this. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: I have added a summary. I hope that clears any ambiguity.

Comment: @ARHAMRUMI  have added a summary but I have just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501273/what-is-the-difference-between-date-now-and-date-now-in-mongoose) question with answers that go into it a bit deeper if you need.